# LoginRedirect with prompt='create' not working in Angular Msal

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, msal-angular

I am trying to redirect the user directly to the sign-up (user creation) flow. Following the MS docs it should be possible by specifying `prompt="create"`.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#send-the-sign-in-request

In both cases it states that the 'create' option is valid and exactly what I need.

However, in practice it doesn't work. I get this error:

```
ServerError: invalid_request: AADB2C90043: The prompt included in the request contains invalid values. Expected 'none', 'login', 'consent' or 'select_account'.
```

This tends to be a recurrent problem with MSAL library: the docs say one thing but in practice it's a totally different reality.

Has anyone encountered this problem or tried to achieve this in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the issue in my environment:***

I run the below auth url for Azure AD B2C:

```
https://kavyasarabojub2c.b2clogin.com/kavyasarabojub2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_signinup&client_id=xxxxx&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fb2capp.com&scope=openid&response_type=code&prompt=login
```

**Received same error:**

```
AADB2C90043 : The+prompt+included+in+the+request+contains+invalid+values.
```

[image]

Also it seems only  below prompts are valid : [implicit-flow-single-page-application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/implicit-flow-single-page-application#get-access-tokens)

Use below Url with prompt=login or anyone of  'select_account', 'consent' and 'none'

```
https://kavyasarabojub2c.b2clogin.com/kavyasarabojub2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_signup&client_id=xxx&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fb2capp.com&scope=openid&response_type=code&prompt=login
```

[image]

- As here , I need user to sign up , I selected signup flow already:

[image]

**`Login=create`** is used in a case where one needs to enable external users to create account or sign up.

For that you may need to enable Enable **`guest self-service sign up via user flows`** by toggling it to yes.

[image]

I donot have such permission in my environment

Please check this to [Add a self-service sign-up user flow - Azure AD - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/self-service-sign-up-user-flow#enable-self-service-sign-up-for-your-tenant)